# HTTP Client SSL Connection setEnabledCipherSuites

Tags: java, ssl, httpurlconnection

I have an app which connects to a server via HTTPS.
The server in question has a weak certificate which utilises RC4 Cipher (default support for which was recently removed from the JDK https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml)
So following upgrade of the JDK, I am seeing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

The release notes specify that you should use SSLSocket/SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites()
to specifically enable certain ciphers.

However, using HttpsUrlConnection, or Apache's CloseableHttpClient, I can only find how to specify the SslSocketFactory. Which doesn't seem to provide function  .setEnabledCipherSuites.

Found this post: [Why does SSLSocketFactory lack setEnabledCipherSuites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320787/why-does-sslsocketfactory-lack-setenabledciphersuites)

My question is:
Is there a way to get hold of the SSLEngine/Socket on an outbound client HTTP request so I can set the cipher suites before the handshake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same issue. Did you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I was able to figure this out.

```
SecureProtocolSocketFactoryImpl protFactory = new SecureProtocolSocketFactoryImpl();
httpsClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost(host, port, httpsProtocol);
```

In the "SecureProtocolSocketFactoryImpl" class you have to override the method public Socket createSocket() for SecureProtocolSocketFactory class.

In that method you will get a socket like this

```
 SSLSocket soc = (SSLSocket) getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(
                    socket,
                    host,
                    port,
                    autoClose
                );
```

So there you will be able to do something like below.

```
ciphersToBeEnabled[0] = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA";
soc.setEnabledCipherSuites(ciphersToBeEnabled);
```

hope you get the idea. If you have any problems please comment below. Note that doing this only will not enable RC4 related ciphers. You will need to modify java "java.security" file in jre/lib/security/ file and remove CR4 form the disabled algorithm list.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to modify java.security in jre/lib/security/ file and remove CR4 form the disabled algorithm list?

Answer (score 0):

For `HttpsURLConnection`, set the system property [`https.cipherSuites`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned SSLSocketFactory doesn't support setEnabledCipherSuites() so can do something like this

```
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory=(SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket=(SSLSocket)socketFactory.createSocket(host,port);
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(CIPHERS);
SSLSocket provides setEnablesCipherSuites();
```